# stacked bar chart in plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

[image: This is what I get]I have an issue in creating the stacked bar chart in plotly dash.

when I tried, the graph looks like stacked with the last variable of the year that is only it considered march.

```
df
    Year    Month   Value
0   2000    Jan    1
1   2000    Feb    2
2   2001    Jan    3
3   2001    Feb    4


import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002],
        ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

rows = zip(data[0], data[1], data[2])
headers = ['Year', 'Month', 'Value']
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
df
data = [
    go.Bar(
        x=df['Year'].unique(), 
        y=df['Month']

    ),
    go.Bar(
        x=df['Year'].unique(),
        y=df['Value']     
    )
]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    title='Stacked Bar with Pandas'

)


fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

I need the graph with x-axis as Year, y-axis as value and stacked x-axis based on the month.

[image: Need Graph like the below]

Comment: What issue? It's not at all clear whether that is the current actual or desired data, what the code is here for, what result you want instead, etc.

Comment: I have edited my question,  I hope it will help @underscore_d

Comment: Sure, thanks, that's better. Could you perhaps also include a screenshot of the current output, and - if you feel artistic! - a mockup of the graph you want instead?

Comment: I have added the expected and current graph. Kindly assist